# Restore Windows 8.1 from Restore Drive - Ubuntu

Tags: usb, windows-8, data-recovery

I want to install **Ubuntu 14.04** on my **Aspire E1-510P-4614**,

So I have created a USB Recovery Drive using **Windows 8.1**

Am I able to install Ubuntu (Erase it all)

and in the future, restore my Windows 8.1

Using that USB Recovery Drive I made?

---

A simple yes or no would suffice.

I can't use a disk and don't want to
dual-boot.

Thanks in advance for any help..

Comment: Please help...?

Answer (score 0):

No you can not. A recovery drive will help you troubleshooting not reinstalling. Please take a full backup on an external hard drive or I recommend you to install Ubuntu alongside windows in dual boot.